# is there any way to handle KeyRelease event in IUP library?

Tags: c, user-interface, events, iup

i only found K_ANY event in the [doc](https://tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/)(Events and Callbacks -> Common -> K_ANY).

how do i handle keypress and keyrelease events separately?
is it possible in this library?

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only on IupCanvas and derived controls using the KEYPRESS_CB callback. It has an extra parameter that indicates if the key is being pressed or released.